# Random errors in Anaconda3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, import, anaconda

```
 C:\Users\jesper>pip Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 3, in <module>
     import pip   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
     from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 22, in
 <module>
     from pip.compat import console_to_str, expanduser, stdlib_pkgs   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 11,
 in <module>
     from logging.config import dictConfig as logging_dictConfig   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\logging\config.py", line 30, in <module>
     import logging.handlers   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 26, in <module>
     import logging, socket, os, pickle, struct, time, re   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 123, in <module>
     class socket(_socket.socket): TypeError: __weakref__ slot disallowed: either we already got one, or __itemsize__ != 0
```

I get this now, and it happened randomly and keeps recurring. I can't use Python at the moment. I tried re-installing the entire conda library and tried different locations for Anaconda. Even tried installing Anaconda for 2.7 and it still didn't work. If someone knows how to fix I'd be in there eternal debt. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "random" would indicate there is _no correlation_ which would be inherently impossible to fix. Do you possibly mean "sporadically" (unpredictable but still likely based on some underlying cause)

Comment: Well yes it's kind of random. The thing is that it just happened between two runs in pycharm. Now I can't use python with command prompt either. Re-installation doesn't help which leads me to believe that it has nothing to do with Anaconda3, which would explain why I can't find anyone with similar problems. Maybe someone had issues with Windows interfering with the libraries in some way?